# Eclipse: showing an interactive map of your project

Tags: eclipse, diagrams

Is there a way to get Eclipse to do something like this:

[image]

It would be SOOOO helpful.

Comment: Consider how difficult that is for a person.   NOW imagine how hard that is to program!  I seriously doubt ANY compiler or interpreter can do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[nWire](http://www.nwiresoftware.com/) provides a visual representation of the components and associations in your code. It's not exactly what you are looking for, but could it will get you a bit closer. It works for Java and PHP.

There is also [Project Code Bubbles](http://www.cs.brown.edu/people/acb/codebubbles_site.htm), which is not the same, but it seems a bit close to what you are looking for.